# how to select top row from group by with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two SQL tables, news and newsSections. I want to to display the top rows from a group by when selecting 4 different types of the news sections. For example:

```
SELECT TOP (4) a.newsID, a.title, a.clicked, a.path, a.newsDate, c.sectionName, a.sectionID
FROM dbo.News a INNER JOIN
     dbo.newsSection c
    ON a.sectionID = c.SectionID
WHERE (c.SectionID = 21) OR (c.SectionID = 23) OR (c.SectionID = 36) OR (c.SectionID = 37)
GROUP BY c.sectionName, a.newsID, a.title, a.clicked, a.path, a.newsDate, a.sectionID
ORDER BY a.newsDate DESC
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would better explain what you want to do.  I added the SQL Server tag.

Comment: What is wrong with current query?

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand about your data model. You have news and news sections. So I would expect the two tables to be related by the news ID. But surprisingly you join by sectionID. How can a news have a sectionID? Wouldn't that make the news a news section? Or is this a simple typo in your query?

Comment: And I don't understand your request. There are news. The news have news sections. You want to show news with sections 21, 23, 36 or 37. So if news A has sections 21 and 23, and news B has sections 21 and 36, and news C has sections 21 and 37, and news D has sections 23 and 36, and news E has sections 23 and 37, that makes five news and a total of ten news sections. But you only want to show four *news*? Or you only want to show four *news sections*? And which, i.e. by what criteria do you decide for certain news or news sections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT n.*, ns.sectionName
FROM dbo.newsSection ns CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 n.*
      FROM dbo.News n 
      WHERE n.sectionID = ns.sectionID
      ORDER BY n.newsDate DESC
     ) n
WHERE ns.SectionID IN (21, 23, 36, 37);
```

Comment: I tried that, but got this message:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: @splitfire . . . That was a typo.  There is no `ON` with `APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

From your query, you're going to the the 4 most recent articles from ALL of the the news sections pooled together -- meaning, you may get multiple articles from a single section and no articles from another section if there has been more recent activity in some sections vs. others.

I'm guessing what you actually want is the most recent article from EACH of the sections. If so, then the reply by Gordon Linoff would do the trick -- except that he left in the 'ON' clause in the query. (Gordon himself pointed this out.) Should look more like this:

```
SELECT n.*, ns.sectionName
FROM dbo.newsSection ns CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 n.*
      FROM dbo.News n 
      WHERE n.sectionID = ns.sectionID
      ORDER BY n.newsDate DESC
     ) n
WHERE ns.SectionID IN (21, 23, 36, 37);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I'm using SQL server 2008. The query looks good, but still gives me that error..